# Blender export to three.js. All matirials have the same grey color

Tags: three.js, export, blender

I'm playing around with some open source 3d models and when I'm trying to export them to three.js json format, all materials are exported in same grey color.
[How model looks like in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMmz.png) (you can see that all materials have different colors)

[How the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ededg.png)

So inside the exported json file all materials have the same color:

```
[{
    ...
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    ...
    "DbgName":"HullPlain.002"
},{
    ...
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    ...
    "DbgName":"HullColor.002"
},...]
```

[here my export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwiIb.png)
I tried different models and I'm getting the same materials settings `"colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5], "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],` for all of them.

Does anyone knows what can cause this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a the `.blend` file, or at least a screenshot of your material settings in Blender? It is hard to guess from the screenshot alone what type of material you've used.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy yes, sure. 
Here is blend files: 
[first](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yo499ufymf3hpqf/X-Wing.blend?dl=0), 
[second](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11i14yexy61sksg/SmallSpaceFighter.blend?dl=0).

for both of them I'm getting the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three.js JSON exporter [does not support Cycles node materials](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12344), and generally [that exporter is no longer recommended](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12903).

I would suggest using [KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) and `THREE.GLTFLoader` instead. It supports Cycles Render, but only if you use the [provided PBR nodes](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/blob/master/docs/user.md). For an easier setup process, use the default Blender Render materials. A quick conversion (I was not careful about getting the right colors) shows this working for your models:

[image: screenshot of small space fighter GLB model]

^Note that you will need to apply modifiers before export, or in the export settings.

three.js r92